# Separate front-end in django

Tags: python, django

I want to divide my app to front-end and back-end in Django project. I have books app inside my project directory, so i placed JS files and **index.html** to `myproject/books/front-end/` dir. Now i just need to render **index.html** in view, but for that it has to be in `myproject/books/templates/`. So i tried to use `render_to_response('../front-end/index.html')` dance, but it just renders 'no file' error.

P.S. Basic idea is to handle all template work by [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and use RESTful API to communicate with server database with Tastypie. Maybe it is bad idea or i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding the /front-end/ folder in your TEMPLATES['DIRS'][] list in your settings.py. Something like

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'books/front-end/'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
          #the usual stuff
        ],
    },
},
]
```

In my project with Django 1.8 I have something similar.

In views.py:

```
def desktop_view(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Comment: Why did you want add it as a comment? It's an answer.